# SQL Server: Left outer join on whether ID exists

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The first three items from table `ProviderValueCard` add their respective amount if = 1. I'm also trying to add 50 to my TotalScore if the `ProviderID` exists in table `SubscriptionsTV`. GroupID is also from SubscriptionsTV in which the condition needs to be met. I beleive I need to have a left outer join in the 2nd query on ProviderID columns from both tables.

```
DECLARE @ProviderID int = '1717';

WITH cte as(
SELECT TOP 1 ProviderID, Time_Stamp,
       SUM(CASE WHEN [AdditionalReports] = '1' THEN 5 ELSE 0 END) as AdditionalReports,
       SUM(CASE WHEN [UniqueReportRequests] = '1' THEN 15 ELSE 0 END) as UniqueReportsRequests,
       SUM(CASE WHEN [SurveyCompleted] = '1' THEN 30 ELSE 0 END) as SurveyCompleted
       --IF @ProviderID EXISTS SUM(THEN 50 ELSE 0 END) 

       FROM ProviderValueCard
       WHERE ProviderID = @ProviderID
       GROUP BY Time_Stamp, ProviderID
       ORDER BY Time_Stamp DESC
    )
        SELECT ProviderID, Time_Stamp, (AdditionalReports + UniqueReportsRequests + SurveyCompleted) AS TotalScore
        FROM cte
        --WHERE GroupID = 2
```

returns

```
ProviderID  Time_Stamp              TotalScore
----------- ----------------------- -----------
1717        2014-08-28 13:03:30.593 45
```

ProviderValueCard table

```
ProviderID  AdditionalReports UniqueReportRequests SurveyCompleted Time_Stamp
----------- ----------------- -------------------- --------------- -----------------------
1717        0                 1                    1               2014-08-28 13:03:30.593
```

SubscriptionsTV table

```
ProviderID  GroupID
----------- -----------
1717        2
```

My final result is this:

```
DECLARE @ProviderID int = '1717';

WITH cte as(
SELECT TOP 1 a.ProviderID, Time_Stamp,
       SUM(CASE WHEN [AdditionalReports] = '1' THEN 5 ELSE 0 END) as AdditionalReports,
       SUM(CASE WHEN [UniqueReportRequests] = '1' THEN 15 ELSE 0 END) as UniqueReportsRequests,
       SUM(CASE WHEN [SurveyCompleted] = '1' THEN 30 ELSE 0 END) as SurveyCompleted,
       MAX(CASE WHEN b.ProviderID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 50 END) as SubscriptionExists

       FROM ProviderValueCard a
       LEFT JOIN SubscriptionsTV b
         ON a.ProviderID = b.ProviderID  
       WHERE a.ProviderID = @ProviderID AND GroupID = 2
       GROUP BY Time_Stamp, a.ProviderID, event
       ORDER BY event DESC, Time_Stamp DESC
    )
        SELECT ProviderID, Time_Stamp, (AdditionalReports + UniqueReportsRequests + SurveyCompleted + SubscriptionExists) AS TotalScore
        FROM cte
```

Comment: Why the downvote? What criteria did I not meet?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I don't think it's clear what your problem is. Sometimes showing desired result along with the result you're getting makes it easier to help on a problem.

Comment: Gotcha, my desired result is to add 50 to my current TotalScore of 45 only if the paramenter `@Provider` is also in the 2nd table `SubscriptionsTV'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that this can be accomplished with a `LEFT JOIN`, and I'd use `MAX()` with a `CASE` statement:

```
DECLARE @ProviderID int = '1717';    
WITH  Subs AS (SELECT DISTINCT ProviderID
               FROM SubscriptionsTV
               )
     ,cte  AS (SELECT TOP 1 a.ProviderID, Time_Stamp,
                      SUM(CASE WHEN [AdditionalReports] = '1' THEN 5 ELSE 0 END) as AdditionalReports,
                      SUM(CASE WHEN [UniqueReportRequests] = '1' THEN 15 ELSE 0 END) as UniqueReportsRequests,
                      SUM(CASE WHEN [SurveyCompleted] = '1' THEN 30 ELSE 0 END) as SurveyCompleted,
                      MAX(CASE WHEN b.ProviderID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 50 END) as SubscriptionExists    
               FROM ProviderValueCard a
               LEFT JOIN Subs b
                 ON a.ProviderID = b.ProviderID  
               WHERE a.ProviderID = @ProviderID
               GROUP BY Time_Stamp, ProviderID
               ORDER BY Time_Stamp DESC
              )
 SELECT ProviderID, Time_Stamp, (AdditionalReports + UniqueReportsRequests + SurveyCompleted + SubscriptionExists) AS TotalScore
 FROM cte
```

Update:  Since multiple providerID's can exist, need DISTINCT, used a 2nd cte above, could also use a correlated sub-select inside the `CASE` statement.

Wasn't paying attention, `ORDER BY` is fine in a cte when `TOP` is used.

Comment: There actually may be more than 1 per ProviderID, do I need a select distinct? I'm also getting errors under these ProviderID's http://i.imgur.com/sCpMYCo.png the first 3 say ambiguous and the last says invalid column

Comment: I also added a comma after the 3 SUM CASE and included the GroupID = 2 in the WHERE.

Comment: I forgot to alias the `ProviderID` references, since we're adding another table with `ProviderID` we have to specify which table to retrieve the value from. That's updated, regarding the multiple provider id's, I think it's best with a 2nd cte, will update presently.

Comment: Not sure where you want your `GroupID` criteria added.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I added what I ended up with in my edit. `event` is a time stamp in the SubTV table I used to elimate duplicate SUMS